# Recover MySQL /var/lib/mysql after update

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I did an update from Mysql 5.5 to 8.0 in a Centos 6 server without dumping the databases to a .sql file, I just copied the /var/lib/mysql directory to another location.

Now if I try to load mysqld service it crashes.

Being naive I deleted all the content of /var/lib/mysql and installed the service again, now it runs but now I do not know how to manually import the DB files to the directory (copy & paste of the folder does not work) in order to do a check of the DB and/or repair it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rysnc should likely already be installed, but if it isn't you would:

`sudo yum install rsync`

Then

```
#make sure mysql isn't running
sudo service mysqld stop

#double check that there is no MySQL PID running
sudo ps aux | grep mysql

#move the new MySQL 8.0 data files out of the way
sudo mv /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql.bak

#copy the original data files back to /var/lib/mysql
#note that the trailing / is required for both paths
sudo rsync -av /path/to/original/mysql/db/files/ /var/lib/mysql/

#change user and group ownership to mysql
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql

#start MySQL
sudo service mysqld start

#run mysql_upgrade, replace {usernamehere} with the actual username
sudo mysql_upgrade -u {usernamehere} -p
```

Update:

You will need to downgrade the binaries to 5.5.  Take a backup of each database once MySQL is running again and then upgrade in the following order:

- 5.6
- 5.7
- 8.0

You will need to run `mysql_upgrade` after each upgrade.

Comment: Did the MySQL service start? Where are getting the timeout error?  What is in the error log?

Comment: Timeout error occurred trying to start MySQL Daemon.
Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]

Comment: You will need to look at at the [MySQL error log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/error-log.html). It should tell you were things are failing during startup of the service.

Comment: I think that there is a memory problem, there are a lot of "[ERROR] [MY-010923] [Server] Table upgrade required. Please do "REPAIR TABLE `wp_comments`"" 

and Error in renaming mysql_index_stats.ibd.

Comment: Did you run `mysql_upgrade` ?